# Why is Github Actions returning null for any .env value accessed using process.env in my javascript?

Tags: github, github-actions

Here is my workflow. Now, ideally, `MIX_BASE_URL` is in `.env` but doing `process.env.MIX_BASE_URL` in my code makes it inaccessible until or unless I put it in my Github secrets.

What if the value can't be predetermined and is set by my build process? I hope there is a way to put a placeholder or enable Github actions to be able to read the .env value because locally it works, in actions it doesn't.

```
name: Deploy to staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

jobs:
  vapor:
    name: Deploy to staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: aligajani/laravel-vapor-action@master
        env:
          VAPOR_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.VAPOR_API_TOKEN }}
          MIX_BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.MIX_BASE_URL_STAGING }}
        with:
          args: "deploy staging"
```

Comment: Try with `${{ env.YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE}}`. As mentioned on documentation, you can use environment variables in jobs

Comment: Where is this documented

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts

Comment: Tried it with ASSET_URL, a variable injected by Laravel Vapor build process, still doesn't show up. I neglected MIX_BASE_URL as a test sample because I found out the .env isn't commited to github so it wont work but ASSET_URL should've definately shown up.

Comment: is this normal if I try to print it and it prints None instead of the value due to github protecting it?